# Recursion error: Maximum call stack size exceeded. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, callstack

This is my code. What is wrong?

```
function roundToNext5(n){
    return n % 5 === 0 ? n :
    roundToNext5(n++);  
}
```

Comment: The postfix `++` operator returns the original value after incrementing. Each call to `roundToNext5()` is being given the same value.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I can use n+1 or ++n, right?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't even consider using increment with recursion, just `n + 1`